# Inheritable (?) controller, action and template

Tags: zend-framework, pimcore

When creating a document as another documents child, it is created with a default controller, action and template settings.

I want to set it up so that the controller, action and template fileds would get the values from their adjacent documents in a parent-child structure.

Is there an out of the box solution to this problem or maybe someone has done this in some other way?

Comment: So you want all documents with the same parent to share some values? How are you doing the routing part of your app? Is the hierarchy reflected in the URLs? What sort of 'values' would you want to be shared?

Comment: Yes, the routing is currently completely hierarchy based. What sor of values? As I have mentioned - controller, action and template dropdown menu values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Out of the box" it's only possible to create named (predefined) document types with controller, action, template values. Those types are available on "add document" context menu in document tree.

But I see two likely solutions:

1. You can define custom `Document_Page` class and overload `create()` method.

   ```php
   public static function create($parentId, $data = array())
   {
       $document = static::create($parentId, $data = array());

       $parent = Document::getById($parentId);
       $document->setModule($parent->getModule());
       $document->setController($parent->getController());
       $document->setAction($parent->getAction());
       $document->setTemplate($parent->getTemplate());
       $document->save();

       return $document;
   }
   ```

   Then you must declare your custom class in `classmap.xml`:

   ```html
   <Document_Page>Website_Document_Page</Document_Page>
   ```
2. Create a [plugin](http://www.pimcore.org/wiki/display/PIMCORE/Example) and define [`postAddDocument(Document $document)` hook](http://www.pimcore.org/wiki/display/PIMCORE/Plugin+Backend+%28PHP%29):

   ```php
   public static function postAddDocument(Document $document)
   {
       $parent = $document->getParent();
       $document->setModule($parent->getModule());
       $document->setController($parent->getController());
       $document->setAction($parent->getAction());
       $document->setTemplate($parent->getTemplate());
       $document->save();

       return $document;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I hope some may find it useful because I have stoped working with Pimcore and hope I will never have to do it again :) I think the second solution is the most logically correct one